# Qt connecting to postgreSQL database without configuring ODBC

Tags: qt, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a postgreSQL database without configuring System DSN with ODBC, I've googled a lot and I've tried a lot of connection strings but they didn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
Here is one of the connection strings i've tried:

`dbConnectionString = QString("Driver=PostgreSQLUnicode(x64)}|
Server="+DBhost+"|Port=%1|Database="+dbname+"|Uid="+username+"|Pwd="+password+"|ByteaAsLongVarBinary=1").arg(port)
db.setDatabaseName(dbConnectionString);`

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Working example without odbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499692/postgresql-libpq-with-qt-in-windows/29503302#29503302)

Comment: You don't need ODBC, it only adds a layer of indirection for no good reason. Qt can use most databases directly, without ODBC.

Comment: Thank both of you, now i can connect to database using QPSQL driver, but now all the prepare statement that i used with QODBC don't work. Can you tell me why?
This is my code:
`
qdb1.prepare("select * from function('c1',?,?,?,?,?,?);fetch all in c1");
        qdb1.bindValue("0",iSensor);
        qdb1.bindValue("1",stGeom);
        qdb1.bindValue("2",stImage);
        qdb1.bindValue("3",stVideo);
        qdb1.bindValue("4",stDateFrom);
        qdb1.bindValue("5",stDateTo);

        qdb1.exec();
`
I'm sure that parameters are right.